How to randomize geometry for array objects?
I'm trying to make wooden structures, like walls, floor, etc. I'm using simple method with Array and Boolean modifiers:

I also want to add more unique geometry to every plank. How can I do it (except manually)? I can imagine a few ways, but I think it's overcomplicated, like using particle system with collection of unique planks.
P.S. When I'm talking about additional geometry I mean something simple, like small deforms, cracks or details like this:


(Using Blender 4.1)
I don't think you can use the Array modifier for that purpose. You could try this Geometry Nodes setup instead. This one randomizes the offset on the X-axis but you can also add randomization for Y and Z.

The result would look something like this:

Take note that the bottom face has to be filled in with additional nodes when you start with a grid, see Geometry Node - Extrude Mesh is not solid. Or you can directly begin with a Cube node instead of a Grid node so you don't have to extrude.
(Using Blender 3.6 or lower)
You can also keep the rectangular cuboid you made with the Array modifier, and then add a Geometry Nodes modifier with the following setup after the Array modifier.


Sorry, I haven't mention it. I'm using Blender 3.6. Will this solution work for me?

Oh. The repeat zone node is only available in 4.0+ but you can keep your array modifier with the cuboid you modeled and then just add another modifier, a Geometry Nodes modifier, with a simpler setup. I updated answer. This modifier will just randomize your vertex offsets.

Thank you! It works.
